# Sharing Meteor APIs/schemas across multiple projects (git repos)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, git, meteor, shared-libraries

I am working on a project that has a few different code-bases (mostly Meteor), but they all use some of the same API code (schemas, publications and methods).

It doesn't seem very intuitive to have one repository and use sub-trees/sub-modules in my case. Maybe I'm wrong and somebody could help clear it up.

An example structure of my project:

```
project-landing-page (meteor app for collecting leads and offering basic account management)
project-app          (an angular/ionic/cordova/meteor app that is distributed via the app store) 
project-worker       (a set of cron-like scripts that are executed in the background to manage the data in the mongo instance)
```

They all share the same schemas, and the two meteor apps use the same methods and publications. It seems a bit cluttered to have one repo for all of this code. Making a branch for the app would also branch the code for the worker scripts. That just seems messy.

Would it be okay to have another repo called "project-apis", that provides the shared code an could be cloned into the other projects? What are the drawbacks? Other than having to run git pull when the "project-apis" repo is updated, I can't really see any.

Would any git-wizards be able to chime in?

Thanks!

Comment: While somewhat of an related idea, but inspired by microservices architecture described in [meteor-tuts](https://www.meteor-tuts.com/chapters/3/microservices.html#Why). I believe not only it's doable but design-wise, it'd be a good idea to have a common place for your shared. I'd advise you to create mono-repo and cross-share your code using symbolic linking.

Comment: The mono-repo is a good idea, and a common pattern. Witness lerna and yarn workspaces. Each app has it's own package.json, and can be versioned separately anyway. If you use symlinks within the project, it is safer than symlinking between separate projects